# IE6 secure and nonsecure error - nothing in Fiddler/no iframes

Tags: html, ssl, internet-explorer-6

I've got the issue of IE6 showing the "secure and nonsecure items" error on an SSL page. Looking into it though none of the usual causes seem to apply. There are no calls to http://, there are no iframes in the page, fiddler and httpfox both show only requests to https:// - what else can i check?

In Firefox and IE there is nothing to suggest there is mixed content at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some strange bugs in IE6-IE8 where you will get mixed content alerts from things that have nothing to do with it at all, such as javascript. For example, on the Air Canada website, you will see this happen.

Comment: any ideas about the kind of things that are likely to be the cause?

Comment: FYI it was being generated by a combined/minified version of prototype and scriptaculous i was using

Comment: Sorry I never bothered to look into what causes the JS glitch, I've been putting that off as long as possible. My solution is to tell coworkers IE6 is entirely insecure and the root of all evil on the internet. Switch to a browser that supports sandboxing technology (like chrome) so they don't get viruses from randomly going to some site or just some XXS attack.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and everywhere I found iframes listed to be a common cause so I did not think to check my regular frames. It turns out IE6 considers a frame without a src to be nonsecure as well as an iframe.